# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (14204,1) into shape (14204)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[This is my code and i m getting this error- ile "", line 4, in

```
dataset[:, 6] = imputer.transform(dataset[:,6].reshape(-1,1))
```

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (14204,1) into
>   shape (14204)..

[image]

Comment: when i do that , it shows me another error which i was previously trying to remove-Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 9.3   5.92 17.5  ... 10.   15.3   9.5 ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: can't you simply do: `imputer.fit(data.iloc[:,6])` or `imputer.fit(data.iloc[:,6].reshape(-1,1))`

Comment: oh thanks now its working fine